# Test class read only user profile allows record creation

Tags: apex, visualforce

Created the following test class which uses a USER with a "Read Only" profile to create an Account and Opportunity which get successfully created and don't throw an exception.

```
    @isTest
public class TestReadOnlyUserCreateOpportunity {    
        public static testMethod void testcreateOpp() {
        // Setup test data
        // This code runs as the system user
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Read Only']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'testacc', Email='testacc9003@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=testacc9003@testorg.com');

        System.runAs(u) {
            // The following code runs as user 'u' 
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
            try
            {  
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Name = 'Test Account';
                insert acc;

                Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
                opp.name = 'The coolest opp';
                opp.AccountId = acc.id;
                opp.CloseDate = date.parse('12/29/2019');
                opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';             
                insert opp;  
            }  catch(DmlException e) {
                System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex run on-platform does not enforce FLS and CRUD for you, even within a `with sharing` class or a `System.runAs()` construct. You are required to [enforce FLS and CRUD yourself](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS) in Apex. New constructs introduced in recent releases, such as the [`Security.stripInaccessible()`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_apex_Security_stripInaccessible.htm) and the SOQL [`WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_enforced.htm#!) clause make this easier, but don't fundamentally change the paradigm.

An exception would occur here only if your code generated it. If that were the case, a `System.debug()` is the wrong construct to validate an exception in a unit test. Rather, code that *should* throw an exception must be wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block that validates the exception and ensures it was thrown:

```
try {
    // run exception-generating code here.
    System.assert(false, 'exception caught');
} catch (DMLException e) {
    System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('EXPECTED MESSAGE TEXT'));
}
```